# how to make the end of the game in pakman when all the dots have been eaten?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to make the end of the game in pakman when all the dots have been eaten?

This is the end game code now

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D co)
{
    if (co.name == "PacMan")
    {
        Destroy(co.gameObject);

        EndMenu.SetActive(true);
        GameObject.Find("EndGameConvas/EndGamePanel/Score").GetComponent<Text>().text = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<Text>().text;
        Time.timeScale = 0;

    }
}
```

This is the point eating code

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.name == "PacMan")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<Score>().ScoreChange(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class for the dots you could use something like

```c#
public class YourDotClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Keeps track of all currently existing instances of this class
    private readonly static HashSet<YourDotClass> _instances = new HashSet<YourDotClass>();

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Register yourself to the instances
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Remove yourself from the instances
        _instances.Remove(this);

        // Check if any instance still exists
        if(_instances.Count == 0)
        {
            // => The last dot was just destroyed!

            EndMenu.SetActive(true);
            GameObject.Find("EndGameConvas/EndGamePanel/Score").GetComponent<Text>().text = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<Text>().text;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.name == "PacMan")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<Score>().ScoreChange(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**However**, you should really rethink/restructure your code and think about who shall be responsible for what.

Personally I would not like the dots be responsible for increasing scores and end the game .. I would rather have a component on the player itself, let it check the collision, increase its own points and eventually tell some manager to end the game as soon as all dots have been destroyed ;)

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is "how do I let the game know the level is over and trigger the end" then just have a variable to hold how many dots are in the level, and every time you eat one and that trigger collider fires, have a counter go up. When the counter equals the total, level ends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this. Just store all of the pacdots in an array and once the array is empty you could end the game.

```
GameObject[] pacdots = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("pacdot");
   
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // pacman collided with a dot
    if (collision.name == "PacMan")
    {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         GameObject.Find("Canvas/Score").GetComponent<Score>().ScoreChange(1);

         if (pacdots.length == 0)
         {
             // All dots hit do something
         }
    }
}
```